# Exit from wait when UI is loaded

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Hello Experts.**

**Problem facing for a Test Execution purpose.**

Firstly, if the solution of my problem exist, you can give me link and i am seeking apology for not searching thoroughly in internet. After all, i am learning with your help.

**Used Code:**

I am using below source code in **typescript**:

```
await new loadUI('Login Page');//loads the UI

//wait to load the UI
await new Promise(res => {
  setTimeout(res, 60000);
});
```

Here, I am waiting for **1 min** to load the UI.

**Problem:**

Here, whenever the UI loads, it waits for 1 min. If it loads after 30 seconds, it waits for 1 min.

**Looking for solution:**

Now i am looking for a solution so that when the UI loads, it exits from wait. No concrete waiting for 1 min.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The very purpose of `await` is to wait just the time necessary for an `async` action to complete, then carry on. Your current code does two things in order. 1. It waits for the UI to load. 2. Then, it starts a 1-minute timeout.

Comment: You can use the "onload" event. Add an event listener which listen to the 'load' event triggered once your UI has been loaded. See more https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: Problem is facing while executing UI test cases.